# Polars qcut return quantile break points

Tags: python, python-polars

With Polars (0.19) is it possible to make qcut return the break-points? These break-points are the numerical value at which the distribution is cut. For a normal distribution, quantile 0.5 will return the break-point ~0. We can return also the labels but these have to be strings. Is there anyway to also return the *quantile* break-point?

It's possible to work around this by making the label just be the break-point as a string then parsing this back out but it feels rather round-about (and hacky).

**Example:**

```py
X = pl.DataFrame({"x": np.random.normal(size=100)})
X.select(pl.col("x").qcut([ 0,0.5, 1], include_breaks=True).struct.rename_fields(["break", "label"])).unnest("x")
```

outputs

```
shape: (100, 2)
┌──────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ break    ┆ label                             │
│ ---      ┆ ---                               │
│ f64      ┆ cat                               │
╞══════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ 2.113793 ┆ (0.07471832756341387, 2.11379302… │
│ 0.074718 ┆ (-2.338473351991288, 0.074718327… │
│ 0.074718 ┆ (-2.338473351991288, 0.074718327… │
│ 2.113793 ┆ (0.07471832756341387, 2.11379302… │
│ …        ┆ …                                 │
│ 0.074718 ┆ (-2.338473351991288, 0.074718327… │
│ 2.113793 ┆ (0.07471832756341387, 2.11379302… │
```

Notice that the `break` column contains the *values* at which the data were split, not the *quantile*, which is what I'm after.

It's possible to emulate what I'm after with the following

```py
y = X.select(
       pl.col("x")
         .qcut(
               [0., 0.5, 1], 
               labels=["0", "0.5", "1", "inf"], 
               include_breaks=True,
         )
         .struct.rename_fields(["break", "label"])
    ).unnest("x").with_columns(
       pl.col("label")
         .cast(pl.Utf8)  # labels are categorical so make them strings first
         .cast(pl.Float64)
         .alias("quantile")
    )
```

which outputs

```
shape: (100, 3)
┌───────────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ break     ┆ label ┆ quantile │
│ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ f64       ┆ cat   ┆ f64      │
╞═══════════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ -0.118428 ┆ 0.5   ┆ 0.5      │
│ 2.90702   ┆ 1     ┆ 1.0      │
│ -0.118428 ┆ 0.5   ┆ 0.5      │
│ -0.118428 ┆ 0.5   ┆ 0.5      │
│ …         ┆ …     ┆ …        │
│ 2.90702   ┆ 1     ┆ 1.0      │
│ 2.90702   ┆ 1     ┆ 1.0      │
│ 2.90702   ┆ 1     ┆ 1.0      │
│ 2.90702   ┆ 1     ┆ 1.0      │
└───────────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: Given that you've already provided a method for doing what you want, you should articulate what you wouldn't find to be "rather round-about (and hacky)". It's clear that what you want isn't built in and any other method of achieving it, might seem as round-about and hacky. You wouldn't want someone to waste their time answering a poorly articulated question, would you?

Comment: Well it's "round-about" in that it involves rendering floats as strings only to then cast them back to floats. If you have a large frame that's a lot of unnecessary work, and also may not be robust; we render the strings in python then parse them back with polars (probably somewhere in rust code?), who's to say that will _always_ round-trip properly.